# IHostedService - persistent task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using `IhostedService` in my ASP.NET core web api application.
As described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/).

Hosted service is running in endless while loop:

```
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
// Logic here
await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
}
```

Service is pulling data from DB and generating reports from it periodically.

Its all working OK, but the service sometimes fails (Exception is thrown and the service exits).
As the background service is critical for the application, is it possible to get it automatically restarted? Or completely exit web api application?

Currently it just exits and web api continues to serve (but serves old / useless data as the service is dead).

Comment: Just put try-catch inside while loop?

Comment: Nothing is provided for you here, you'll need to do your own error handling.